# Run shell commands from python and string concatenation

Tags: python, dropbox

I am trying to adjust the "post to dropbox" services for Snow loepard (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1144075/Post%20to%20Dropbox.zip).
I dont want the public URL, but a shortened one from goo.gl

Therefor I am using these shell commands:

```
curl -s --data-urlencode "url=http://link.com" http://googl/action/shorten | grep "googl" | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "=" } ; { print $2}' | pbcopy
```

Now the python script does this to copy a dropbox URL for all the files it just copies in the public folder to the clipboard:

```
    pasteURLs = []

for file in copied_files: # for all elements in our list
    components = file.split(os.sep)    # seperate the path
    local_dir = os.sep.join(components[5:])    # cut off the beginning
    local_dir = urllib.quote(local_dir) # convert it to a URL (' ' -> '%20', etc.)
    #construct the URL
    finalURL = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/%s/%s' % ( dropbox_id, local_dir )
    pasteURLs.append(finalURL) # add the current URL to the string

copy_string = "\n".join(pasteURLs)
os.system( "echo '%s' | pbcopy" % (copy_string) ) # put the string into clipboard
```

I have to admit I dont know anything about python, but from what it looks like, I need to change the last two lines with this:

```
shortURL = []
for thisURL in pasteURLs:
        shortURL = os.system( curl -s --data-urlencode "url=http://link.com" http://googl/action/shorten | grep "goo.gl" | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "=" } ; { print $2}' | pbcopy )
    shortURLs.append(shortURL)

copy_string = "\n".join(shortURLs)
os.system( "echo '%s' | pbcopy" % (copy_string) ) # put the string into clipboard
```

But my problem is, how to put the correct URL in the command? As u can see it says `http://link.com` But it should use `thisURL` instead.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think your os.system call should look something like this:

```
os.system("curl -s --data-urlencode \"url=%s\" http://goo.gl/action/shorten | grep \"goo.gl\" | awk -F\\\" '{print $(NF-1)}' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = \"=\" } ; { print $2}' | pbcopy " % thisURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I wrote the script for you and used a much simpler command pipeline.  Not that the entire thing could be done in python without curl, but here it is.

```
import subprocess
thisURL = 'http://whatever.com'
pipeline = []
pipeline.append('curl -s -i --data-urlencode "url=%s" ' % thisURL +
    'http://goo.gl/action/shorten')
pipeline.append('grep Location:')
pipeline.append('cut -d = -f 2-')
#pipeline.append('pbcopy')
command = "|".join(pipeline)
link, ignore = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True).communicate()
print link
```

Comment: Basically same as @Daniel's but triple quotes avoid having to escape so many embedded quotes.

Comment: Oh you need to use subprocess.Popen then.  Let me fix this up.

Comment: See my answer for the implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already provided the core of this: use quotation marks around your command, use a format string to insert the value and consider using subprocess in order to actually get the output from the command.

However, if you, like me, think this is getting a bit too convoluted, go have a look at [this example](http://segfault.in/2010/10/shorten-urls-using-google-and-python/) on how to do the actual shortening in python. If you're new to python, this might mean you'll need to read up on your [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to understand it. (It also looks like you might need [a custom module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/), but then again it appears to only be used if you get an exception...)